# getting message in console but it does not update Rails + vuejs

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to do a chat with rails (actioncable) and vuejs.

I'm getting correct answer from actioncable but i can not update the messages in front end: You can take a look to this image:

[image]

This is my vue code:

```
<template>
  <div class="room-page">
    <div class="container page">
      <div class="row room-content">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div>
            <h3>{{room.title}}</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr/>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 offset-md-2">
          <MessageEditor :id="id">
          </MessageEditor>
          <div class="card-messages">
            <Message v-for="(message, index) in filteredItems " :id="id" :message="message" :key="index">
            </Message>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
import store from "@/store";
import MessageEditor from "@/components/Message/MessageEditor";
import Message from "@/components/Message/Message";
import { FETCH_ROOM, FETCH_MESSAGES } from "@/store/action-types";

import ActionCable from "actioncable";
var cable = ActionCable.createConsumer("ws://localhost:3000/cable");

export default {
  name: "Room",
  props: {
    id: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  components: {
    MessageEditor,
    Message
  },

  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    cable.subscriptions.create("RoomChannel", {
      connected: function() {
        console.log("connected to rails actioncable Yay!");
      },
      disconnected: function() {
        console.log("disconnected");
      },
      received: (data) => this.messages.push(data)
    }),
      Promise.all([
        store.dispatch(FETCH_ROOM, to.params.id),
        store.dispatch(FETCH_MESSAGES, to.params.id)
      ]).then(data => {
        next();
      });
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["room", "messages"]),
    filteredItems: function(messages) {
      return this.messages.slice(0, 20);
    }
  },
  watch: {
    messages(newMessage, oldMessage) {
      //muy atentos a cambios en el getter messages
      console.log("messages. We are be able to make a changes");
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

this is my store vuex:

```
import {
  FETCH_ROOM,
  FETCH_MESSAGES,
} from "./action-types";
import { SET_MESSAGES } from "./mutation-types";
const initialState = {
  room: {
    title: ""
  },
  messages: []
};

export const state = Object.assign({}, initialState);

export const actions = {
  [FETCH_ROOM](context, roomId, prevRoom) {
    // avoid multiple network call if room exists
    if (prevRoom !== undefined) {
      return context.commit(SET_ROOM, prevRoom);
    }
    return RoomsService.get(roomId).then(({ data }) => {
      context.commit(SET_ROOM, data);
      return data;
    });
  },
  [FETCH_MESSAGES](context, roomId) {
    return MessagesService.get(roomId).then(({ data }) => {
      context.commit(SET_MESSAGES, data);
    });
  }
};

export const mutations = {
  [SET_ROOM](state, room) {
    state.room = room;
  },
  [SET_MESSAGES](state, messages) {
    state.messages = messages;
  }
};

const getters = {
  room(state) {
    return state.room;
  },
  messages(state) {
    return state.messages;
  }
};

export default {
  state,
  actions,
  mutations,
  getters
};
```

This is my `Message` component:

```
<template>
  <div class="card">
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item">{{ message.content }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import {
    mapGetters
  } from "vuex";
  export default {
    name: "Message",
    props: {
      id: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      message: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

This is `MessageEditor` component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <list-errors :errors="errors">
    </list-errors>
    <form class="card message-form" v-on:submit.prevent="onSubmit(id, message)">
      <div class="card-block">
        <textarea class="form-control" v-model="message" placeholder="Write a message..." rows="3">
              </textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"> Post Message </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import {
    mapGetters
  } from "vuex";
  import ListErrors from '@/components/ListErrors/ListErrors'
  import {
    MESSAGE_CREATE
  } from '@/store/action-types'

  export default {
    name: 'MessageEditor',
    components: {
      ListErrors
    },
    props: {
      id: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      content: {
        type: String,
        required: false
      },
    },
    data() {
      return {
        message: this.content || null,
        errors: {}
      }
    },

    methods: {
      onSubmit(id, message) {
        this.$store
          .dispatch(MESSAGE_CREATE, {
            id,
            message
          })
          .then(() => {
            this.message = null
            this.errors = {}
          })
          .catch(({
            response
          }) => {
            this.errors = response.data
          })
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Updated** with @acdcjunior code, i'm getting:
Cannot read property 'messages' of undefined
    at `Subscription.received`

This morning was working well, but suddenly it's broken. The rails action cable server is working fine.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe turn `received: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }` into `received: (data) => this.messages.push(data)`?

Comment: @acdcjunior exactly!. That was the problem :). Anyway, if you think that other kind of approach is better than this approach, i would like to know it!

I’ve update my question adding `MessageEditor` and `Message`components as well.

Comment: @acdcjunior Please, add your best response to accept it and give you score. Thank you!

Comment: Update: suddenly, it's broken again. i don't know what's wrong :(

Comment: What exactly is broken? Are you still using `received: (data) => this.messages.push(data)`? If so, can you update the question?

Comment: @acdcjunior Yes, i'm using `received: (data) => this.messages.push(data)`. the question has been updated!. Thank you! I'm getting this error with your fix: `Cannot read property 'messages' of undefined
    at Subscription.received` Thank you

Comment: I would change `beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {` to `created() {`. And `Promise.all([
        store.dispatch(FETCH_ROOM, to.params.id),
        store.dispatch(FETCH_MESSAGES, to.params.id)
      ]).then(data => {
        next();
      });` to simply `store.dispatch(FETCH_ROOM, this.$route.params.id);        store.dispatch(FETCH_MESSAGES, this.$route.params.id);`. This will delay the configuration of the ActionCable, but may just be what you need.

Comment: @acdcjunior The last one code seems that is working fine. Please post your response to give you my vote up! Thank you!

Comment: There you go. I tried to explain it a bit better. You can upvote and/or accept if you wish, of course!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering:

```
  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    cable.subscriptions.create("RoomChannel", {
      connected: function() {
        console.log("connected to rails actioncable Yay!");
      },
      disconnected: function() {
        console.log("disconnected");
      },
      received: (data) => this.messages.push(data)
    }),
      Promise.all([
        store.dispatch(FETCH_ROOM, to.params.id),
        store.dispatch(FETCH_MESSAGES, to.params.id)
      ]).then(data => {
        next();
      });
  },
```

The vue-router's `beforeRouteEnter` hook is executed **before the component is instantiated, so there will be no `this`** (and so `received: (data) => this.messages.push(data)` won't work).

My suggestion is to move that loading from the `beforeRouteEnter` to [the `created`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#created) [lifecycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram) of the component.

With these changes, the code above would become:

```
created() {
   cable.subscriptions.create("RoomChannel", {
     connected: function() {
       console.log("connected to rails actioncable Yay!");
     },
     disconnected: function() {
       console.log("disconnected");
     },
     received: (data) => this.messages.push(data)
   }),
   store.dispatch(FETCH_ROOM, this.$route.params.id);
   store.dispatch(FETCH_MESSAGES, this.$route.params.id);
}
```

The `Promise.all()` was removed because there's no need to wait for the dispatches anymore (since there's no need to call `next()` now).